# Error when adding flag tinyInt1isBit=false in the MySQL JDBC url

Tags: mysql, aws-glue

I got this error when adding tinyInt1isBit flag in mysql database:

"An error occurred while calling o89.getDynamicFrame. The connection property 'tinyInt1isBit' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false?useCursorFetch=true' is not in this set."

I have no idea how to fix this error.

Here's my connection options to connect to the database

```
datasource_oi = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options( 
'mysql', connection_options={ 
"url": "jdbc:mysql://blablabla:3306/dbtable?tinyInt1isBit=false", 
"user":"user", 
"password":"password", 
"dbtable":"dbtable" } )
```

Can someone help me how i must do to fix this error? Thank you.

I tried to add "useCursorFetch=true" to my jdbc url string as the error message said that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Use single quotes around true or false

Comment: it still show the same error then i addedd single quote.

here's my jdbc url after i added single qoute: 

"jdbc:mysql://blablabla:3306/dbtable?tinyInt1isBit='false'"